# Valgrind shows possible memory leak associated with ncurses

Tags: c, memory-leaks, valgrind, ncurses

I used valgrind to check for memory leaks in my C program which gave the following as ouput:

```
HEAP SUMMARY:
    in use at exit: 439,553 bytes in 236 blocks
  total heap usage: 6,329 allocs, 6,093 frees, 7,033,556 bytes allocated

Searching for pointers to 236 not-freed blocks
Checked 1,409,520 bytes

9 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 11 of 89
   at 0x483E7C5: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:380)
   by 0x4E1434E: strdup (in /usr/lib/libc-2.33.so)
   by 0x48AB816: ??? (in /usr/lib/libncursesw.so.6.3)
   by 0x48AEA80: _nc_tiparm (in /usr/lib/libncursesw.so.6.3)
   by 0x488BF9E: ??? (in /usr/lib/libncursesw.so.6.3)
   by 0x488C9AD: newterm_sp (in /usr/lib/libncursesw.so.6.3)
   by 0x488CCCA: newterm (in /usr/lib/libncursesw.so.6.3)
   by 0x4888E32: initscr (in /usr/lib/libncursesw.so.6.3)
   by 0x10A56F: main (blind.c:72)

24 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 34 of 89
   at 0x483E7C5: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:380)
   by 0x4E7F7E7: tsearch (in /usr/lib/libc-2.33.so)
   by 0x48AB831: ??? (in /usr/lib/libncursesw.so.6.3)
   by 0x48AEA80: _nc_tiparm (in /usr/lib/libncursesw.so.6.3)
   by 0x488BF9E: ??? (in /usr/lib/libncursesw.so.6.3)
   by 0x488C9AD: newterm_sp (in /usr/lib/libncursesw.so.6.3)
   by 0x488CCCA: newterm (in /usr/lib/libncursesw.so.6.3)
   by 0x4888E32: initscr (in /usr/lib/libncursesw.so.6.3)
   by 0x10A56F: main (blind.c:72)

168 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 65 of 89
   at 0x48435FF: calloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:1117)
   by 0x48AB78E: ??? (in /usr/lib/libncursesw.so.6.3)
   by 0x48AEA80: _nc_tiparm (in /usr/lib/libncursesw.so.6.3)
   by 0x488BF9E: ??? (in /usr/lib/libncursesw.so.6.3)
   by 0x488C9AD: newterm_sp (in /usr/lib/libncursesw.so.6.3)
   by 0x488CCCA: newterm (in /usr/lib/libncursesw.so.6.3)
   by 0x4888E32: initscr (in /usr/lib/libncursesw.so.6.3)
   by 0x10A56F: main (blind.c:72)

LEAK SUMMARY:
   definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
   indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
     possibly lost: 201 bytes in 3 blocks
   still reachable: 439,352 bytes in 233 blocks
        suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all

ERROR SUMMARY: 3 errors from 3 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

as far as I can tell the memory leak is initiated via `initscr()` in my main function.
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32411962/16734995) answer to a similar question suggests that it is normal for ncurses to have some memory leaks however the leaks shown in that post are "still reachable" while the leaks in my program are "possibly lost" and I can't tell if the above still aplies.

here's part of my main function for reference:

```c
initscr(); // initialize ncurses
cbreak();  // disable input buffering
noecho();  // disable echoing input in the screen

curs_set(0); // return cursor to beginning of the screen

clear(); // clear the screen

// for every character in the terminal window
for(int i = 0 ; i < win.ws_row ; i++) {
    for(int j = 0 ; j < win.ws_col ; j++) {
        // for all characters in every row 2 pixel inputs are accessed,
        // `u` for the upper pixel and `l` for the lower one.
        // each half-braille character can contain from 0 to 4 dots
        // so the normalized array (0..1) is converted to
        // the closest integer approximation from 0 to 4
        int u = dround(4 * pixels[2 * i][j]);
        int l = dround(4 * pixels[2 * i + 1][j]);
        mvprintbraille(i, j, random_braille(u,l));
    }
}

char c;
while(true) {
    // read characters until q is pressed at which point exit the program
    c = getch();
    if(c == 'q') break;
}
endwin();
```

I am pretty certain there are no memory leaks in any of the other functions or pointers shown so am I doing something wrong in terms of `ncurses`? perhaps there is a function to free the memory allocated by initscr that I missed? Or are the possibly lost bytes harmless?

edit: I was asked to provide a minimal working example which is well, this

```c
#include <ncurses.h>

int main() {
    initscr(); // initialize ncurses
    endwin();

    return 0;
}
```

the valgrind output as far as leaks go is identical so I'm not sure what to think

Comment: I'd assume that those "possibly lost" are just pointers that `valgrind` loses track of because ncurses moves them to point to the middle of some internal buffer to manage data. It's hard to tell without a [mre]. If I run your example without the `for` loop I only get "still reachable" blocks when the program terminates, so the drawing operations that you are doing might be the ones moving internal ncurses pointers around.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli the whole program is located in the [github repo](https://github.com/alex-unofficial/blind) if you want to take a look but the compilation is still pretty bad so it might be a pain. I'll try creating a mwe and updating the question nonetheless

Comment: Aside: `getch()` returns 257 different values.  Better as `int c; ... if(c == 'q' || c == EOF) break;`

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica well spotted. I will change that

Comment: @MarcoBonelli I added a mwe but erm well it's pretty minimal.. I'm not sure if perhaps I am using valgring wrong

Comment: @Alex dunno, I don't get any "possibly lost" with your two examples. `libncurses` 6.2 and `valgrind` 3.16.1.

Comment: This answers your question: [cannot fix memory leak in ncurses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42903568/cannot-fix-memory-leak-in-ncurses)

Comment: @ThomasDickey I'm sorry but I'm not sure how exactly to use the patch. for one I am using ncurses 6.3 so I don't know if that makes a difference and I also can't seem to connect to the invisible-island.net server to download the patch in the first place. And if i did, I installed ncurses via pacman so must I reinstall it from source to apply the patch?

Comment: valgrind says it is "possibly lost" because it cannot tell if the program made a copy of the pointer to the memory (its analysis is incomplete).  The `_nc_tiparm` path is a recent issue which was fixed in development, overlooked because in the usual tests, valgrind said there were no leaks :-)